# How can we swap two elements in an array?

Tags: java, arrays

The problem I am trying to solve is as follows:-

Given an array of ints length 3, return an array with the elements "rotated left" so {1, 2, 3} yields {2, 3, 1}

I came up with the following code:-

```
public int[] rotateLeft3(int[] nums) {
  for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
   swap(nums[i],nums[i+1]);
  return nums;
}

public void swap(int a,int b)
{
 int temp = a;
 a = b;
 b= temp;
}
```

However, it is not running successfully. In case of C++, I could have passed references as arguments and the problem would have been sorted then why is not happening here?

The following code is working:-

```
public int[] rotateLeft3(int[] nums) {
  int temp = nums[0];
  nums[0] = nums[1];
  nums[1] = temp;
  temp = nums[1];
  nums[1] = nums[2];
  nums[2] = temp;
  return nums;
}
```

But this code is complete brute-force writing and I am not liking it very much. Can you please suggest how I can make the first approach work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a rotation that isn't limited by size, try:

```
public int[] rotateLeft(int[] nums){
  if(nums.length == 0)
    return new int[0];

  int temp = nums[0];
  //This loop starts at index 1 because we are moving
  //    elements left, and 0 can't move left.
  for(int index = 1; index < nums.length; index++){
    nums[index-1] = nums[index];
  }

  nums[nums.length-1] = temp;
}
```

Comment: It's the same logic (shifting of elements) used in insertion sort. I could have used this as well.

Answer (score 6):

All parameters in java method calls are passed by value. You need to pass in the array and the two indexes you want to swap.

```
public void swap(int[] array, int a,int b)
{
 int temp = array[a];
 array[a] = array[b];
 array[b]= temp;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As you have said the problem is passing by reference, C does it - Java doesn't. There are plenty of other ways to achieve the same ends though.

The simplest way is to pass the array and the two indexes to your swap function rather than the contents of the array at that index.

Answer (score 3):

you can also use the xor swap without the `temp` variable ;)

```
public void swap(int[] array, int ind1, int ind2) {
 array[ind1] ^= array[ind2]
 array[ind1] ^= (array[ind2] ^= array[ind1])
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you call the swap method , you are passing the values inside your array, but that method does not return the a and b values. Yes, that could be done in C/C++ with the use of pointers, but java does not have it.

Xynariz's code provide a way of doing the shift that is not limited to array size.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a swap function with a single line usage pattern, but the calling format is not typical:

```
public int[] rotateLeft3(int[] nums) {
  for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    nums[i+1] = swap(nums[i], nums[i]=nums[i+1]);
  return nums;
}

// swaps any number of same type objects
public <T> T swap(T... args) {
  // usage: z = swap(a, a=b, b=c, ... y=z);
  return args[0];
}
```

This works because the first argument is passed into swap before the assignments happen in rest of the arguments.